# date parser solution python

Tags: python-3.x, dateparser

while parsing the date using 'dateutil parser' and even by 'moment parser' in python for the date dd/mm/yyyy eg 04/05/2019 it reflects this 05/04/2019 i.e it takes month as the date and vice versa. while if i try the same thing for a date greater than 12 will give the correct output, any solutions ?

```
import moment
print(moment.date('05/04/2019')) //date:05 month:04 year:2019
```

output: 2019-05-04T00:00:00+05.50 //considers date as month and vice versa which is wrong.

but if i try this

```
import moment
print(moment.date('13/04/2019')) //date:12 month:04 year:2019
```

output: 2019-04-13T00:00:00+05.50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dayfirst=True`

**Ex:**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse 

print(parse('05/04/2019',dayfirst=True))
# --> 2019-04-05 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the format for the date:

```
moment.date("13/04/2019", "%d-%m-%Y")
```

otherwise the library will use a default format, obviously since there are only 12 months any number greater than that will be treated as day or year.

Please check the documentation
https://github.com/zachwill/moment